# Unity obb downloader failed

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk-expansion-files

I am using ***Unity obb downloader plugin*** for my app because it has more than 50mb.
I have .apk and .obb, they are uploaded and on alpha test on Play Store.
When I download the application from store, it works. But when I delete .obb file and try to download it manually with ***obb downloader plugin*** it goes:

```
Looking for resources...
Download failed because the resources could not be found.
```

Did anyone have this problem?

NOTE:
I did change

> dl_service.SetStatic ("BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY",...

And expansion name is: (current version of apk is 3)

> main.3.packagename.obb

It is working when downloading normally.

**EDIT:**

I am using Unity 5.1.1. Is it working in Unity 5?

**EDIT 2**

It started working by itself.

Comment: What is the name of your OBB file it must follow a specific formate

Comment: It is well formatted: main.3.packagename.obb (current version of app is 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some odd reason, it started working by itself.